# Identifying the elements when extracting texts from two labels using protractor and angular js

Tags: angularjs, protractor

My application has the structure below:

```
<ul ng-repeat="variable in link.variables" ng-show="SearchboxCtrl.showData" class="ng-scope"> 

<li class="ng-binding"> Member Since:  </li> 
<span class="ng-binding"> 2010-01-01 </span></ul>
```

"Member Since" and "2010-01-01" are two labels. I am trying to extract the text from these lables. But protractor is failing to locate the elements.
I am using `element(by.binder)` but it's not working.

Can you please help in this regard?

Comment: <ul ng-repeat="variable in link.variables" ng-show="SearchboxCtrl.showData" class="ng-scope"> 

<li class="ng-binding"> Member Since:  </li> 
<span class="ng-binding"> 2010-01-01 </span></ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `element(by.binder)` to following :

```
 this.AllItems = element.all(by.repeater("variable in link.variables"));
 this.labels = this.AllItems.all(by.css('.ng-binding'));
```

and then you can get the text of all labels

```
 this.labels.getText();
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestion and it is giving "[object Object]" in console. can you please help

Comment: i figured out. thank you. issue fixed. thank you for help

Comment: `this.labels.getText();` returns a promise you need to resolve this `this.labels.getText().then(function(txt){ console.log("text of labels="+txt) });`